# llegal string offset 'tittle' in C:\xampp\htdocs\2\2\mvc\model\includes\catclass.php on line 594

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Please help to resolve this error illegal string offset 'tittle'
here goes the jquery

```
 data:{option:'catapply',sr:$(":input").serialize()},
```

and the catapply php data

```
if($_REQUEST['option']=='catapply'){

    $sc  = serialize($_POST['sr']);

    mysql_query("insert into user_data(uid,mid,cid,scid,data) values('$session->userid','5','5','5','$sc')");
```

now  i am unserializing the above data in db stored by using the above method

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from user_data  where uid='$session->userid'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $un=unserialize($row['data']);
    $tittle=$un['tittle'];

   echo $tittle;
```

Comment: Should the field be called 'title'?

Comment: try to see if `$un` is not false after the `unserialize()` function, seems like your serialized data are damaged

Comment: Why jQuery tag? [deleted tag] also use real words! [edited it]

Comment: `var_dump($un)` What value does it contain?

Comment: yes its just giving the error shown in tittle of this Q.

Comment: I am betting `$un` is not an array at some point.

Comment: string(153) selg=find+givers+of%3F&to=&select_category=7&msg=&tittle=ddddddd&s=zxzxc&s=ur+ot‌​her+profile+link&s=zxc&s=zxc –

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

> The converted value is returned, and can be a boolean, integer, float, string, array or object.
>
> In case the passed string is not unserializeable, FALSE is returned and E_NOTICE is issued.

You could try using the error suppress operator (@), but I wouldn't [*normally*] recommend that.  You should make sure that `$row['data']` isn't empty.

```
if (!empty($row['data']) {
    // here we're suppressing errors
    // @see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php
    $un = @unserialize($row['data']); 
    if ($un) {
        // ... so on and so forth
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is you're sending data that's been serialized by jQuery, which is _not_ the same as PHP.

Comment: You need to post the _entire_ AJAX portion of your script.  Period.

Answer (score 0):

after this line

```
$un=unserialize($row['data']);
```

try with this

```
var_dump($un) OR print_r($un)
```

and see what `$un` contains.

```
$un['tittle']
```

this will not evaluate because this syntax is for array evaluation not for string, and your `var_dump($un)` result is string.

You are serializing using this

```
$sc  = serialize($_POST['sr']);
```

and unserializing

```
$un=unserialize($row['data']); // this is query data it should be
$un=unserialize($sc);
```

and if you want `title`  data us this

```
$tittle=$row['tittle'];
```

Comment: i used var_dump and got this..givers+of%3F&to=&select_category=7&msg=>=giving&tittle=asdasd&s=ur+real+name&s=asdas&s=da&s

Comment: string(153) selg=find+givers+of%3F&to=&select_category=7&msg=&tittle=ddddddd&s=zxzxc&s=ur+other+profile+link&s=zxc&s=zxc

Comment: yes,thanks for ur response, i halve also tried ur edit but it did not work!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17102/discussion-between-rasim-fryal-and-yogesh-suthar)